# Extracting data using view

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to find trip leg details from a transport db using a view.

How ever I am not able to do so. I need to make a query that finds all trips with no more than 2 legs, that is trips with 1 or 2 destinations, and displays trip number (TripNo), trip origin (Start), the first destination (Stop1), and the second destination (Stop2) in the following format.

```
 TripNo START STOP1 STOP2
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 05 CatmanSt Chinatwon MayflowerSt
 03 MayflowerSt Auckland
```

This is the following table.

```
TRIP( TripNo,LicenseCardNo,CarReg,TRIP_DATE,)
PRIMARY KEY (TripNo),
FOREIGN KEY (LicenseCardNo) REFERENCES DRIVER(LicenseCardNo),
FOREIGN KEY (CarReg) REFERENCES TRUCK(CarReg)

( 1, DR1, 'SJG123', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-135 )
( 2, DR2, 'GBC222', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-135 )
( 3, DR1, 'GBC270', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-133 )
( 4, DR3, 'SJG123', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-130 )
( 5, DR22, 'SJG123', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-130 )
( 6, DR22, 'GBC222', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-124 )
```

TRIPLEG TABLE

```
TRIPLEG(  TripNo, LEGNo, DEPARTURE, DSTINATION )    
CONSTRAINT TRIPLEG_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (TripNo, LEGNo),
CONSTRAINT TRIPLEG_UNIQUE UNIQUE(TripNo, DEPARTURE, DESTINATION),
CONSTRAINT TRIPLEG_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (TripNo) REFERENCES TRKTRIP(TripNo) );

INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES( 1, 1, 'Armidale', 'Liverpool');
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES( 1, 2, 'Liverpool', 'Adelaide');
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES( 1, 3, 'Adelaide', 'Armidale');
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES( 3, 1, 'MayflowerSt', 'Auckland');
....
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES( 5, 1, 'CatmanSt', 'Chinatwon');
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES( 5, 2, 'Chinatwon', 'MayflowerSt');
```

I need to implement using a view. How to do it ? I am not able to retrieve it at all. Should I use left join or right join

Comment: The last record, should be `INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES( 5, 21, 'Chinatwon', 'MayflowerSt');` ??

Comment: @KiroConeski It should be 2. I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select st.tripno, 
       st.departure as "START",
       st.dstination as stop1,
       stp1.dstination as stop2
from tripleg st
  left join tripleg stp1 
         on stp1.tripno = st.tripno 
        and stp1.departure = st.dstination
where st.legno = 1
  and st.tripno in (select tripno
                    from tripleg 
                    group by tripno
                    having count(*) < 3);
```

Here is a SQLFiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f773/1

If you need to create a view out of that, just run:

```
create or replace view v_short_trips
as
select ...
```

For more details on how to create a view based, please [refer to the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8004.htm)

Comment: OK, I give up :) @a_horse_with_no_name, shouldn't you move the last part of the query starting with` `where st.legno=1...` before the left join?

Comment: @KiroConeski: no. Due to the left join *every* leg will be returned and I need only the first one. If that is moved into the join condition, only the first leg would be considered at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It works fine. But i need to use 2 views inside the codes to extract the data. How to go about it ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i need to implement creatw view 2 times and the ouput should be like yours

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my question i have stated that i need to implement view. My first line and the last line indicates it.

Comment: @user1571494: again: I have shown you how to create a view. Where does this requirement for a 2nd view come from.